# UIImage Stretching issue in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell, stretch

I had Used `UICollectionView` to show three images in each cell in portrait and landscape mode using `AutoLayout`. Fetch images from server to load in `UICollectionView` data. In iphone 4s and 5 working little better but iphone 6 and 6 plus Image stretching issue in portrait and landscape mode. I had tried AspectFit but i need to fill image in full space. I had spent more time with this so How to solve this issue? please let me your suggestions.

Thanks in Advance

FYI, Screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AspectFill`

`AspectFit` Keeps the aspect ration, but showing all the image, therefore it won't fill your imageView, and `AspectFill` keeps the aspect ratio, and filling your imageView, therefore it wont show all the image, think about it like sort of cropping the image to fit in your imageView.